# Add circles to jQuery ui-datepicker-calendar

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

In my website I have use the jQuery complement called datepicker for representing a calendar.

I want to add to the days, some circles that will simulate like a legend. That's what I am trying to simulate:

[image]

For example each color could represent different information.

Thats the class for create a circle.

```
.dot {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Thats my basic calendar page for doing some tests.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>datepicker demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="lib/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="datepicker"></div>

<script>
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I add the dot class to the jQuery UI Datepicker?

Comment: Bit confused. Are you trying to set 3 dot with different color ? *(Like in 19)*.

Comment: Because the logic is not implemented. Any day could have 0 dots or 3 as max. It depends on the events of each day-

Comment: Can you share demo link?

Comment: @vadivela I want to create something like that, but with the JQuery datepicker https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/event-calendar-evo.html